# Compose navigate to screen that already in backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to have navigation that looks like this:

-I have three screens: "Login", "Registration", and "Account recovery";

-from each screen, I can navigate to any other;

-when I navigate from the "Login" screen to "Registration" and then return to the "Login" (clicking the button "Go to login"), I want to have the same screen as at the beginning, not a new one.

Now, each time, when I go back to "Login", I get a new screen :(

My NavHost:

```
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.Login.route) {
        composable(route = Screens.Recovery.route) {
            RecoveryScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.Login.route) {
            LoginScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.Registration.route) {
            RegistrationScreen(navController = navController)
        }
    }
```

Guide me which way to dig?

Answer (score 5):

I am late, but it may help someone check Jetnews sample app in GitHub,
navigate like this

```
navController.navigate(JetnewsDestinations.HOME_ROUTE) {
            // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
            // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
            // on the back stack as users select items
            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
            }
            // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
            // reselecting the same item
            launchSingleTop = true
            // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
            restoreState = true
        }
```

this avoid multiple back stack also restore state of previous opened destination

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that it is a new screen? Let me guess, you must be looking at some state of the screen, for example, filled textfields would be empty, scrolled lists would be reset, checkboxes would be reset or something to this effect. You see it does not matter whether you are calling the stuff from the backstack. The thing is, the moment a Composable is no longer visible on screen, it is destroyed, resetting all the state to the default values. That is, it will always be recomposed upon navigation request. What you need here is to store all that state inside a viewmodel. Then, reference the state from the viewmodel itself. Create state variables in the viewmodel with default values, then always reference from the viewmodel itself. This way, upon recomposition, the data would be fetched from the vm, and it will still be the correct data since the vm is not destroyed.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But since I am using Compose, I don't need to use any fragments and multiple activities, so how do I manage to keep my VM instances?
Resetting all fields of LoginVM, RegistrationVM & RecoveryVM, when user authorized seems not the best solution.

Comment: You must. That is the way of doing it. Otherwise, you will need to manually destroy the viewmodels, then re-create if required, but why not just create a simple method in each of the VMs to reset all the values at once?

Comment: This approach forces me to call the reset method of each VM (in that case 3 VMs) for each of these screens, it's just a simple example. But what if I have ten different screens in a back stack, and I want to log out, in this case, I need to reset all of the VMs. I think it's an error-prone solution.

Comment: I dont think this is the optimal solution, I known i need store the data in my VMs, but when you navigate from a tab to other tab the content makes a flickering effect, the animations start again, the scroll lost his value, I dont think this is good for the user.